# За что отвечает class caption в bootstrap3?

Tags: bootstrap

Выполняю урок по bootstrap 3 (модальные окна). Есть html разметка:

```html
<li class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
     <a href="#landon" data-toggle="modal"><img src="images/landon-thumb.jpg" alt="Dahlia Landon, President and CEO."></a>
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>Dahlia Landon</h3>
    <p>President &amp; CEO</p>
    <p><a href="#landon" data-toggle="modal"></a></p>
  </div>
</li>
```

Вопрос: За что отвечает class="caption"? Это класс Bootstrap? Если да то что он делает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечает за заголовок, да этот класс есть в Bootstrap, он позволяет назначить стили.

Answer (score 1):

Инструменты разработчика (f12) показали что класс .caption присваивает следующие параметры:

```
padding: 9px;
color: #333;
```

И да это действительно класс bootstrap.